# $J = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : f(2) = 0\} = (x-2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In an introductory lecture about ideals we discussed a few examples and I didn't understand the remark given by the lecturer on the last example. Here it is:

Let $J = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : f(2) = 0\}$. Then $J = (x-2)$. Indeed,

$$J = \{f(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] : f(x) = (x-2)g(x)\} = \{(x-2)g(x) : g(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]\} = (x-2).$$

Our lecturer said it is important to notice that the last equality follows from that fact that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a commutative ring with identity. I didn't understand the importance of his remark, specifically, why does the last equality follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a commutative ring with identity?

Comment: Did you mean $J=\langle x-2 \rangle$?

Comment: @KennyLau Yes, absolutely. I also don't know why he used parentheses.

Comment: Look clearly. They are angle brackets. $\langle x-2 \rangle$ means the ideal generated by $x-2$.

Comment: Some authors (like Hartshorne and Atiyah / MacDonald) just use regular parentheses instead of angle brackets. So angle brackets are not ubiquitous.

Comment: @Arthur: Seconded. The authors Lang, Kaplansky, and Bourbaki also use parentheses.

Comment: So gauss lemma is the way to go. Or you know single variable polynomial ring over a field is PID by existence of long division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal of a ring $R$ generated by an element $r$ is defined as the smallest two-sided ideal in $R$ that contains $r$, i.e. the intersection of all ideals of $R$ containing $r$.

So, taking $R=\mathbb{Q}[x]$, $r=x-2$, the statement is that if $J=\{rs:s\in R\}$, then $J$ is the ideal of $R$ generated by $r$.

The fact that $R$ is commutative ensures that $J$ is a two-sided ideal of $R$, and the fact that $R$ has identity ensures that $J$ contains $r$. It's straightforward to see that any other ideal of $R$ containing $r$ will contain $J$, hence $J$ is generated by $r$.